# Rails exclusion query with active record -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How would I use active record in this case:

I have two tables: Users, Admins

Admins can be users also and thus have a user_id in their table.

I'd like to **Select all users that DO NOT have a user_id set in the admins table**

NOTE: This is just an example case. If this was a real case then of course I wouldn't have two different tables for users and admins.

Edit: Again, I know the semantics of doing it like this is terrible db design -- but it's just an dummy case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:conditions` to include a `NOT IN`:

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => ['user_id not in (?)', @admins.map( &:id )])
```

---

**OR** you can code it into a User's `scope` ( a.k.a. `named_scope` prior to Rails 3.x ):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :not_admin, lambda { |admins| { :conditions => ['user_id not in (?)', admins.select( &:id ).join( ',' )] }
end
```

And use it as:

```
User.not_admin( @admins )
```

---

**OR** in order not to depend on `@admins` variable being passed you can use `joins`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :not_admin, joins( :admin ).where( :admins => { :user_id => nil } )
end
```

Comment: Is there a way I can make that a `scope` so I could put it in the model instead of controller?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work -- I keep getting a `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error

Comment: My models are `user` and `admin`. Do I need to reference some of the fields in the lambda as `self.id` maybe?

Comment: The following seems to work, is it correct also? ... `scope :not_admin, includes(:admin).where(:admins => {:user_id => nil})`

Comment: the example I gave assumes that you have "admins" to pass => hence it expects a variable (0 for 1). If you need a user to always be "connected" to admins, you can use `joins` ( `includes` loads admins eagerly ).